# Recyclerview within exoplayer doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml, exoplayer, android-framelayout

I have my app using exo player within a framelayout with a recyclerview that shows the server list , so the issue is when i click anywhere on player that normaly hides the controls like play pause progressbar fullscrn and so the recyclerview but the app crashes but if i click the recyclerview before clicking anywhere on the player everything works fine like recyclerview hides just like other controls in exoplayer.

```
simpleExoPlayerView.setControllerVisibilityListener(new PlayerControlView.VisibilityListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            Log.e("Visibil", String.valueOf(visibility));
            if (visibility==0){
                rvServer.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                imgBack.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                imgFull.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                if (listSub.size()!=0) {
                    imgSubtitle.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                }
            }else {
                rvServer.setVisibility(GONE);
                imgBack.setVisibility(GONE);
                imgFull.setVisibility(GONE);
                imgSubtitle.setVisibility(GONE);
            }
        }
    });



<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/player_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
            android:id="@+id/video_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_controls"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_server_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SubtitleView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_subtitle"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_subtitle"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

'''Error Log

```
2019-09-09 09:37:26.318 21523-21523/com.demo.app E/vTYpe ::: 1
2019-09-09 09:37:30.392 21523-21523/com.demo.app E/STATE PLAYER:::: false
2019-09-09 09:37:44.515 21523-21523/com.demo.app E/Visibil: 8
2019-09-09 09:37:44.518 21523-21523/com.demo.app E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
2019-09-09 09:37:44.518 21523-21523/com.demo.app E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
2019-09-09 09:37:44.521 21523-21523/com.demo.app E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.com.demo.app.DetailsActivity$11.onVisibilityChange(DetailsActivity.java:746)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerControlView.hide(PlayerControlView.java:576)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView.onTouchEvent(PlayerView.java:798)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10024)
```

Comment: Please add the error log

Comment: am a noob Apologies if what i added isn't the correct error log

Comment: It is looking like a null pointer exception. Please add the declarations and initialisations of views in tha activity

Comment: can you elaborate !!

Comment: you are actually trying to use a view before it is initialised, please add the declaration of `RecyclerView`.